# Import Postgres 8.3 database in Postgres 10.5

Tags: postgis, postgresql-10, postgresql-8.3

I have a database in Postgres 8.3 (and PostGIS 4.2), which I need to import in Postgres 10.5.

I am a DB newbie and would appreciate any pointers to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/static/migration.html), you have to use `pg_dump`:

> #### 24.4.1. Migrating data via pg_dump
>
> To dump data from one major version of PostgreSQL and reload it in another, you **must** use pg_dump; file system level backup methods will not work. (There are checks in place that prevent you from using a data directory with an incompatible version of PostgreSQL, so no great harm can be done by trying to start the wrong server version on a data directory.)

(emphasis mine, this is no different for version 10 than for version 9).

You might be able to get [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238305/4751173) to work; it's a simple one-liner but I've never used it myself.